# What is the other side of socket in android

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, linux-kernel, asyncsocket

I'm porting a GB device to ICS and was having issues with the Bluetooth.

The issue arises when the native method - connectNative tries to connect on the socket created to listen to the Call Audio stream.

the socket is created in the file

> android_bluetooth_BluetoothSocket.cpp

using

```
socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_SCO)
```

But when the connectNative function is called, it throws error - 93 - Protocol not supported.

```
The exception reported in the framework is as follows:
Bluetooth HS/HF: BEFORE mOutgoingSco.connect()
BluetoothSocket.cpp: --> INSIDE connectNative IN android_bluetooth_BluetoothSocket.cpp
BluetoothSocket.cpp: connectNative
BluetoothSocket.cpp: --> TYPE_SCO_WBS | TYPE_SCO
BluetoothSocket.cpp: ...connect(161, SCO) = 93 (errno 93)
BluetoothSocket.cpp: --> INSIDE connectNative ABOUT TO THROW jniThrowIOException(env, errno);
Bluetooth HS/HF: BluetoothSocket could not connect
Bluetooth HS/HF: IOException - Printing StackTrace
System.err: java.io.IOException: Protocol not supported
System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:233)
System.err:     at com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree$ScoSocketConnectThread.run(BluetoothHandsfree.java:476)
```

From which part of the android code will the socket be heard and written to?